# R - Nearest non-zero neighbours from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, minimum

I have a table of how closely areas are related on given variables. I would now like to extract the names of the neighbouring area.

```
matrix <- data.frame(Area =c("A","B","C","D"),A=c(0.0,0.1,0.1,0.9),B=c(0.1,0.0,1,0.7),C=c(0.1,1,0.0,0.3),D=c(0.9,0.7,0.3,0.0)) %>%
    remove_rownames() %>%
    column_to_rownames(var="Area")
```

I am not quite sure how to do this anyway, but what could complicate matters is that the it needs to be the non-zero minimum to account for the diagonal and there is potential that two areas could have the same value. The *sort* of result I would be looking for from the above data is something like:

| Area | ClosestN |
| --- | --- |
| A | B;C |
| B | A |
| C | A |
| D | C |

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Did you try something like `apply(matrix[,-1],1,\(x) names(which(x[x>0]==min(x[x>0]))))`?

Comment: I think that has worked! I'll do some manual checking to validate it, but it looks promising. Thank you very much.